# Delineating coastline with panchromatic imagery

Tags: classification, imagery, vectorization

I have a panchromatic satellite image with a large coastline area and my goal is to delineate this coastline with a maximum accuracy and minimum amount of manual work. What is the best option to accomplish this?

I do not have either DEM nor other spectral bands, so these solutions do not work:

- [Delineating large scale watershed?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116208)
- [Watershed delineation with meandering river?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189305)
- [Extracting coastline as vector from landsat 8 imagery?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183107)

Here is a small area of the original 2-meter satellite image I have:

[image]

Comment: If that's all you have then you really have a serious problem. You could give supervised classification a go but I have my doubts that it will return anything like what you need. If you can source some infra red bands your chances of automatically classifying sea/shore edge get better. Perhaps you could start with SRTM to approximate your coastline and use that to limit your processing area to save some cleaning up later.

Comment: I would explore image segmentation with Python's opencv package. Here is a blog post that will hopefully get you started: https://learndeltax.blogspot.com/2016/02/segmentation-using-cannywatershed-in.html. Python's scikit-image package is also excellent for digital image processing: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/

Comment: I got a [decent result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuYX0.png) thresholding then grouping low values . What software do you have available?

Comment: @Luke you name it. What would you recommend? Your thresholding seems pretty good, although there are some brighter water areas present on this image, too

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the information about those packages, especially scikit-image! Do you have any experience of converting non-georeferenced outputs of those algorithms into georeferenced ones (i.e. [detected contours](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-contours-py) to shapefiles)?

Comment: As long as you know the corner coords, you can georeference the image with gdal and python: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116872/8104